# using notifyDataSetChanged() in ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I defined a **ListAdapter** on the following line:

```
setListAdapter(
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
```

Now I want to use **notifyDataSetChanged()**

What is the right way to call it ?

What is the `id` of the adapter ?

Comment: Why do you want to use it? It is used when the contents of the list is changed. Else just leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

More preferably, declare your `adapter` object outside a method (i.e. at global level) so it is accessible in other methods within the class too.

Answer (score 1):

When `listItems` get changed and you want to display that in the ListView at that time it's significant to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`; so use the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after listItems get updated